# conda config change default env directory

Tags: conda

conda create -n EvnName python=3.6 keeps installing my Env in user home instead of the env directory of my Anaconda installation /data/anaconda3/envs

conda info gives me

```
Current conda install:

           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.1.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : /data/anaconda3  (read only)
default environment : /data/anaconda3
   envs directories : /data/anaconda3/envs
                      /home/tlinden/.conda/envs
      package cache : /data/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /home/tlinden/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /home/tlinden/.condarc
```

/home/tlinden/.condarc only contains:

```
envs_dirs:
  - /data/anaconda3/envs
```

The reason I always want to install the env in /data/anaconda3/envs is because we have very limited space in the home directory

Answer (score 5):

the reason the environment was installed in the user home was because of the permissions for the /data/anaconda3/envs directory, after changing that new environments install in the /data/anaconda3/envs directory

Answer (score 0):

The `(read only)` in your `conda info` suggests `conda` cannot install the new environment to the Anaconda installation directory thus it puts the new env into your home directory.

Fix the permissions and rerun `conda info`. If it shows `(writable)` then you should be able to install to Anaconda dir.