# put a network drive as a folder path in spyder(anaconda)

Tags: path, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to use files from a network drive (e.g. \**192.168.17.33**\something...).

Anaconda is installed on my computer (e.g. C:\...).

When i'm just putting this path to a path folder line in Spyder, it types that it's an error.

I've seen a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158684/anaconda-installation-points-to-network-drive-as-home-folder-cannot-start-spyd). But it's not exactly what i need.

Is it possible to make it in the way i need?

P.S. I can't just copy these files on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible to use 3 version of spyder(3.3.6 in my case) to get the access to such a folder path(that contains ip address).

Comment: The problem is that Spyder 3 is not maintained anymore, so it won't receive any bugfixes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem will be fixed in Spyder version **4.1.0**, to be released during March 2020.